# Appengine Backend Task Dispatcher: A More Economical Version

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a job dispatcher for appengine, and the default scheduler always winds up firing up 3-4 instances that do all the work, some overflow instances that might take thousands of tasks, or only a couple and then sits there burning cpus doing nothing.

My task involves processing jobs for many different sized domains, sometimes there's huge throughput, and other times it's one user with 10,000 models to update; if I turn the normal appengine task scheduler loose, it fails in two ways: 1) backends never shut down, and when memory hits the cap, java gc makes an instance thrash and act like it's almost a zombie yet never shut down {and still take/hold jobs}, and 2) many domains have a single user that takes far longer than all the others to process, and this keeps a backend alive long after the rest of the domain has finished.

These tasks must run throughout the day, and it takes multiple backends to handle fanout, so I can't just dump them all on a B8 and call it a day., so we need a dispatcher to manage how tasks get allocated to backends.

Now, I don't want to pay datastore ops on every task just to save a few minutes of cpu time, so my plan of attack {please critique} is to use a static ConcurrentHashMap in RAM, start each run() in a try, have every deferred task put it's [hashcode, startTime] in at startup and remove(hashcode) in a finally. There will be one such map per backend instance that's running jobs, wrapped in a method, BackendCounter.addToLiveMap(this); it's .size() serves as a running total of how many jobs are alive on that backend {with timestamp to detect zombie jobs that run >10 minutes}. The job dispatcher can fire off a worker thread per instance to monitor how many jobs, excluding itself, are running in that instance, and keep a ranked list in memcache of which instances have how many tasks alive. If one instance drops below a threshold of X live tasks, pick an overflow instance to defer to, then have the method BackendCounter.addToLiveMap(this) throw an exception I can catch to tell jobs to just schedule themselves to a new instance {ChangeInstanceException#getNewTarget()}. This way I can prevent barely-used instances from getting new jobs so they have a chance to shut down, paying only for some memcache ops and fanout only pays a write and delete to static map.

That takes care of problem two, which is the instance-hour killer. As for problem one, which is how to prevent one instance {usually instance 0 and 1} from hitting peak memory and start turning toward the dark side, I am torn between two options.

On the one hand, I can use the expected call to BackendCounter.addToLiveMap(this) throws ChangeInstanceException and simply check memory:

if (((float)Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory())<0.9) throw new ChangeInstanceException(getOverflowInstance()); 
This naive approach will simply tell any instance approaching it's memory limit to send all new work elsewhere.

On the other hand, I could keep instance 0 and 1 for handling overflow {and toggle between which of the two gets new jobs to give them chances to shut down}, then send the fanout to instances 2+, which will only run until they drop to say, 10 or 15 jobs in parallel. The fanout is pretty consistent, and only takes a couple minutes, so instances 2, 3 and, at most, 4, will need to turn on, and be given time to turn off while a different instance gets hit with more load. 
The only thing I'm afraid of is if jobs starting bouncing from one instance to another, which can probably be overcome with a redirect header limit to skip throwing ChangeInstanceException.

Any thoughts or advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply use pull queues, and have your backends grab tasks off the queue whenever they need more work? You can use whatever logic you want to decide when that should be the case. Or alternately, stop using backends, and use the task queue instead, which will handle instance startup, shutdown, and allocating tasks to instances for you.

Comment: Our frontends are configured with low resource allocation because they are never allowed to do any heavy lifting.  This keeps client-facing responses snappy w/out being expensive, so we have to use backends to get the resources necessary.  I will look into using the pull queues, and having backend instances pull off work until they hit memory limit, and then stop pulling, return, and wait to die.  That or just kill the instance with  LifecycleManager.getInstance().beginShutdown(30);